# Linear Algebra Proof for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

Could someone possibly help me in proving this:

Let $A$ be the augmented $m \times (n + 1)$ matrix of a system of m linear equations
with $n$ unknowns.

Let $B$ be the $m \times n$ matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the last column.

Let $C$ be the matrix in row reduced form obtained from $A$ by elementary row operations.

Prove that the following four statements are equivalent:

1. The linear equations have no solutions.
2. If $c_1,\ldots , c_{n+1}$ are the columns of $A$, then $c_{n+1}$ is not a linear combination of $c_1,\ldots , c_{n}$.
3. Rank$(A) >$ Rank$(B)$.
4. The lowest non-zero row of $C$ is $(0, \ldots , 0, 1)$.

I have been told a good approach would be to show that 1 $\iff$ 2, 2 $\iff$ 3 and 3 $\iff$ 4 however I have got nowhere significant so far.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Please see the attachment for my working so far.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Good effort to post the photo also, but please upload a suitable dimensions file!

Comment: Hopefully this works slightly better now! I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: i don't think $4$ is true. you can add any number of zero rows at the bottom of the augmented matrix.

Comment: it states that it is the lowest non-zero row :)

Comment: @MattAllegro I have now manage to successfully prove that 3 and 4 are equivalent, I am now only struggling with showing 1 and 2 are equivalent and 2 and 3 are equivalent. Any help with the remaining cases would be greatly appreciated. And thank you for your time so far :)